# Can I free my data immediately after send() in blocking mode?

Tags: c, sockets

the docs say for send:

> When the message does not fit into  the   send  buffer  of  the  socket,
>          send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in non-block-
>          ing I/O mode.  In non-blocking mode it  would  return  EAGAIN  in  this
>          case.   The select(2) call may be used to determine when it is possible
>          to send more data.

I am in blocking mode, doing something along the lines of:

```
buf = malloc(size);

send (socket, buf, size);

free(buf)
```

Assume but is very large, larger than the buffer can hold at a time (so it would need to go into the buffer as two chunks lets say). Anyways, in blocking mode, which I'm in, after send, can I feel safe that the data is fully copied or dealt with and thus deletable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In blocking mode, `send` blocks until I/O is complete, or an error is triggered. You should check the returned value, because a `send` operation does not guarantee that the number of bytes sent is the same number of bytes passed as third argument.

Only when `send` returns a value equal to the size of the buffer sent you can be sure that the whole block has been copied into kernel memory, or passed through device memory, or sent to the destination.

Comment: So I should have a while loop continuuing to send the remaining data until size - so_far == send(but + so_far, size - so_far)?

Comment: Yep! Also take care of signals. The process could receive a signal and that will interrupt the system call. In that case, it is not an error, but you must simply reissue the `send` operation

Comment: Will that result in send returning -1 with errno being set to something specific (EINTR?) Or will this return 0?

Comment: Get Richard Stevens' "Unix Network Programming". In the first chapters he discusses all about how to use system calls so signals and transient errors can be handled safely.

Comment: `send` returns 0 if nothing has been sent. If it returns <0, then `errno` must be check. EINTR will indicate that a signal interrupted the operation

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Yes, you can free the buffer after the send() call successfully returns (without errors) when the file descriptor is in blocking mode.

The reason for this is based on the blocking concept itself: The send() call (targeting a blocking file descriptor) will only return when an error occur or the requested `size` bytes of the data in the `buf` is buffered or transmitted by the underlying layer of the operating system (typically the kernel).

Also note that a successful return of send() doesn't mean that the data was transmitted. It means that it was, at least, buffered by the underlying layer.